# In Python regex, how do I make the maximum number of line breaks to be 2?

Tags: python, regex, string

Let's say I have text like this:

```
jessica\n\n\nhello\n\n\n\nhow are you doing?
```

How can I use regex to determine **if there is more than 2 line breaks**, replace it with 2 line breaks max.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> foo = "jessica\n\n\nhello\n\n\n\nhow are you doing?"
>>> re.sub('(\n{1,2})\n*', '\g<1>', foo)
'jessica\n\nhello\n\nhow are you doing?'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Another, simpler and perhaps easier-to-understand solution:

```
import re
foo = "jessica\n\n\nhello\n\n\n\nhow are you doing?"
re.sub('\n\n\n+', '\n\n', foo)
```